# Div z index not working

Tags: css-float, z-index, transparent, css-position

i have a pop up coffee slideshow on the homepage - [theCoffeeLocator.com](http://thecoffeelocator.com) (click "advantages" to open slide.

When opened, the slideshow darkens out the rest of the webpage with a semi transparent.
My top nav bar div (id="topstrip") will not sit behind the darkened div (id="jdarken").

Any ideas
thanks

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here? Otherwise this question is too localised - when your page gets fixed, this question will become useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#topstrip` (z-index: 995) is placed within the `#header` (z-index: 994) within `#back`.

The `#jdarken` (z-index: 996) is placed within the `#contentarea` (z-index: 1) within `#back`.

Since `994>1`, all children of `#header` will be drawn above all children of `#contentarea`. The `#jdarken` is in a different stacking context (separated by a z-indexed node in the DOM-tree) than `#topstrip`, their relative z-indices don't matter.

As a solution, *I suggest removing z-index from `#contentarea`*. This will place `#jdarken` to the same stacking context as `#header`, and thus `#jdarken` will be stack above the `#header` (and above `#topstrip`), since `996 > 994`. If I understand correctly, the z-index of `#topstrip` is unused as well, and you can remove the attribute without consequences.

It is also true that the element must be `position`ed for the z-index to matter (`fixed` will do); however, this condition is satisfied here.

Comment: Thanks. Removed the z-index=1 from content and that solved.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the z-index property to work, the element should have a position attribute either relative, absolute or fixed.

When I checked your source code, I noticed your grayed-out element is located inside some other elements, z-index behaviour is affected by the properties of parents,

Try to relocate your id="jdarken" div to bottom of your page and then try.

Comment: `position: fixed` will work as well.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mentions that, the answer is edited.